# How can I pass multiple generators to FunAnimation in Python?

Tags: python, generator, subplot

I want to create two or more subplots from two or more generator functions using FuncAnimation. My code for creating a plot from a single generator function looks like this:

```
from data import Data

gen = someGeneratorFunction(dataIn)

def animate(frame):
    axs.cla()
    axs.set_xticks([])
    axs.set_yticks([])
    axs.bar(list(range(Data.data_count)),  # X
            [d.value for d in frame],  # data
            1,  # width,
            color=[d.colour for d in frame],  # colour
            ).get_children()
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=gen, interval=1 ,repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

And what I'm trying to do would look something like:

```
gen1 = someGeneratorFunction1(dataIn)
gen2 = someGeneratorFunction2(dataIn)
```

Then I would somehow need to combine generators gen1 and gen2 (which may not have the same length) before passing them to FuncAnimation. I've tried using

```
gen = zip(gen1, gen2)
```

but then I'm actually passing a zip object and not a generator object to FuncAnimation.

Is there some way to combine the generators?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Isn't `zip` object a generator? can you explain why you cannot pass it?

Comment: I don't know whether a `zip` object is a generator. Actually I can pass it to FuncAnimation. I though that the entire generators were then being passed all at once to my function animate, rather than being passed frame by frame as is normally the case (and is certainly the case in my working code where I successfully pass just one generator). But I've just realised I may have been mistaken. Now I've got the combined generators (variable `gen`) passed to the animate function and when I set a breakpoint it seems it's just one frame per generator.

Comment: But when I try to unzip using `gen1, gen2= zip(*gen)` I get the error 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)'. I'll keep working on it and post any progress...

Comment: Sorry, that was not a question (or rather it was rhetorical): `zip` is a generator and can combine multiple generators to form one. Also, you cannot do `a, b = zip(*gen)` (or any generator for that matter). Genrators don't  return anything outside of the context of iteration.